# docker command won't run in Debian

Tags: linux, docker

I have 2 Jenkins jobs. Both should create docker image. 
I try to do so by "docker image build -t server-img ." Linux console is returning:

```
error checking context: 'syntax error in pattern'.
```

The streange thing is, that it is working for another jenkins job. 
I have done same steps and I'm having different results.
The only difference is that working job is building npm application. Second one should create dotnet app.

I've tried put Dockerfile in dfferent folder with no result. What can I do more?

Edit: Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /application

RUN dotnet restore Api/Api.csproj

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish Api/Api.csproj -c Release -o out


# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /application
COPY --from=build-env /application/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
```

I don't think it's dockerfile issue since linux not starting this. I don't have dockerignore for now

Comment: Post the Dockerfile and .dockerignore if you have one please.

Answer (score 0):

I did full restart of docker (it was last try before reinstall it in dev mode). Now I see that "Sending build context to Docker daemon", so that is progress.
 Steps from here fixed problem: https://gist.github.com/bastman/5b57ddb3c11942094f8d0a97d461b430

Still, there is an issue, after
`FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk AS build-env`

I get

`failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 3: unpigz: skipping: <stdin>: corrupted -- crc32 mismatch`

but it's not relevant to orginal question.